# What type of qualifier do we use to ensure users could only use landscape mode on a tablet?

Tags: android

Which of the following qualifier I need to use to ensure landscape mode on a tablet?

- Orientation
- Orientation, Screen Width
- Orientation, Smallest Screen Width
- Layout direction, Screen Width

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want something like this, in your Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
......
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force each activity to use Landscape (Phone or tablet)

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:name=Activity">
```

But... if you want to do the "best way"

You need to add a Layout to the landscape mode.

```
MyProject/
    res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large landscape
            main.xml
```

Check [THIS](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)